# How to Hide navigation buttons in some steps on react stepzilla

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-stepzilla

I have five steps on react stepzilla but on first step I wanted to hide next button. I have tried:

```
    const steps =
        [
          {name: 'Step 1', component: <PaginationPage1 showNavigation={false}/>},
          {name: 'Step 2', component: <PaginationPage2/>},
          {name: 'Step 3', component: <PaginationPage3/>},
          {name: 'Step 4', component: <PaginationPage4/>},
          {name: 'Step 5', component: <PaginationPage5/>}
        ];
```

which doesn't help me. How can I hide the button on step 1?

Answer (score 1):

Use your parent component's state in conjunction with the `onStepChange` callback:

```
function App() {
  let [showNavigation, setShowNavigation] = useState(false);
  let stepzillaProps = {
    onStepChange: step => setShowNavigation(step === 0 ? false : true),
    steps,
    showNavigation
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StepZilla {...stepzillaProps} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-fire-n8muu)